# Two set of references in the same manuscript...reference1 and reference2

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have written a comprehensive survey paper with 130 references...the reviewers of one journal have suggested me to include two set of references in the reference section, one for the  core 91 papers that is basis of the study and 39 other references in the second list...also the style for the first list should be  [S1], [S2] etc while the second list should be normal [1], [2] etc..
I am using bibtex and a single .bib file for references.what is the solution that requires minimal changes

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You could take a look at the `multibib` package.

Comment: Since you explicitly mention BibTeX and it sounds like you are submitting to a journal (which probably will not be able to accept `biblatex` submissions) I have removed the `biblatex` tag.

Comment: Yes I don't want to use biblatex, as I have strict deadline and cant migrate to it...